# Robolectric Test Looping without getting finish

Tags: kotlin, integration-testing, robolectric, dagger-hilt

I'm trying to do integration test with robolectric and hilt testing, and when i add this block on gradle and set max sdk into 33, the test just looping without and end.

```
testOptions {
  unitTests {
    includeAndroidResources = true
  }
}
```

Robolectric Annotation:

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner::class)
@Config(application = HiltTestApplication::class, manifest = Config.NONE, maxSdk = 33)
```

Comment: It's unlikely that that Gradle config leads to an infinite loop. You should debug more and see where the real problem is. Do you get any output while running the test task? How about if you enable Gradle debug logging?